# Javascript behind button error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Hi I am getting this error

Chrome - **'Unexpected token {'**

Mozilla - **'missing ; before statement'**

when clicking on a button, couldn't understand where I am going wrong. Please review my code below and guide me accordingly.

---

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/31.0/integration.js")}

var CamId = '{!JSENCODE(Campaign.Id)}';

var result = sforce.apex.execute("CrtWlcomCallCampaign","welcomeCalls",{parentId:CamId});
sforce.debug.trace=true;

alert{'Welcome call campaign is initiated'};
```

---

here method welcomeCalls returns void.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
alert{'Welcome call campaign is initiated'};
```

you need:

```
alert('Welcome call campaign is initiated');
```